# Filtering a model by date selected to sum in the view (passed as a param)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

All right, I've been stuck on this problem for 6 days. Good news: I've learned an immeasurable amount about the MVC structure while trying to self-solve. Bad news: still haven't solved it.

*cue help*

In my app, I have 3 data sources (technically 4 if you count sessions). A user who has many budgets and has many transactions.

### Controller

I am currently summarizing the combination of the 3 in the User controller:

```
#users_controller.rb
def my_budget
  @transaction = current_user.transactions
  @month = params[:search]
  @budget = current_user.budgets
  @user = current_user 
end
```

### View

In my view, I display each user's budget (**Column 1**) in comparison to the sum of their transactions (**Column 2**) based on type (for this example, 11 correlates to "total income" in my database). Then, I calculate the difference between the two (**Column 3**).

```
#my_budget.html.erb
<% @user.budgets.each do |budget| %>
  <tr>
    <td><h3 class="section-header">Current Income:</h3></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="section-sub-header">Gross:</td>
    <td class="section-value"><%= number_to_currency(budget.income_per_month) %></td>

    <td class="section-value"><%= number_to_currency(@user.get_transaction(current_user, 11)) %></td>

    <td class="section-value difference-value"><%= number_to_currency(@user.total_difference(budget.income_per_month, current_user, 11)) %></td>
  </tr>
```

Obviously, this information is useless. For example, if the user keeps track of their transactions all through April, they will forever have a negative budget because **Column 2** and **Column 3** currently compare the monthly budget to ALL transactions occurring since the user created an account. So, I have tried many attempts at creating an ability to select a month to view, then summarize the data by that value.

### Partial Search

In one of my partials, located at the top of the view I have (specially formatted to where the user can only select a month and day in the format MM/YYYY):

```
#_classic_view.html.erb
<%= form_tag(my_budget_path, :method => "get") do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], name: "startDate", id: "startDate", class: "date-picker form-control", placeholder: "Select Month" %>
  <%= submit_tag "Sort", :name => nil, class: "btn-submit-user text-center", style: "padding: 5px" %>
<% end %>
```

### Model

Here is an excerpt of my model:

```
#user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
    attr_accessor :search
    has_many :budgets
    has_many :transactions

...

# attempt at pulling the param via search
  def self.search(search)
    where("created_at LIKE ?", "%#{@search}%") 
  end

...

# Get transaction sum for the specific sub-category
  def get_transaction(user, type)
    if search
      total_value = user.transactions.where("transactions.sub_category" => "#{type}").search(@search).sum(:amount)
    else
      total_value = user.transactions.where("transactions.sub_category" => "#{type}").sum(:amount)
    end
  end
```

### My Attempt at console.log Ruby Style

I have been through the run-around of accessing the params just to see what I'm working with in the view (oh how I wish Ruby had a simple console.log):

```
#my_budget.html.erb
<h2 class="text-center"><%= @user.current_month(@month) %> Summary</h2>

#user.rb
def current_month(val)
  if val
    current = val
  else
    current = Date.today.strftime("%B %Y")
  end
    current
end
```

Please help with:

1. **SOLVED** Is my use of get_transaction() in the User.rb correct? Specifically, how I call Transaction. as an entire class.
2. I know you should not access params according to the MVC structure, But how do I pass this information to my model or view (since I'm not traditionally looping through a @transaction variable)?
3. Is my search/sort method even viable for my implementation in the model, view, and controller?

Thank you!!

Edit:

**Solved #1**: I was not using Transaction correctly. I did this because you cannot access the "current_user" method in the model, but you CAN pass it in as an argument in the view. I adjusted my code to display this fix.

Comment: oh! so you solved it, I was so busy in writing down the answer :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a scope in model like

```
  class Transaction < ApplicationRecord

    scope :by_month, -> (year, month_name = '') {
      month              = Date::MONTHNAMES.index(month_name.capitalize)
      first_day_of_month = Date.new(year, month, 1)
      last_day_of_month  = Date.new(year, month, -1) # Gives you the last day of month
      where("transactions.created_at between ? and ?", first_day_of_month, last_day_of_month)
    }

  end
```

This will act as a filter. Access it from controller wisely.

If you want to find sum of `:amount` then you can do like

```
Transaction.by_month(2016, 'October').sum(:amount)
```

---

For transaction sum of a user for that month

```
User.find(2).transactions.by_month(2016, 'October').sum(:amount)
```

Comment: I love all of this! Thank you! I will do furthermore research on the power of scopes. One thing: how do I pass the parameter (in this case the MM/YYYY) into the model method?

Comment: Separate out the year and month data from `params` object and fetch from controller. If you have integer as month data then `Date::MONTHNAMES[month_index]` will give you like 'October'.

Comment: One of my core issues is accessing the param since it's not an actual value stored in my database and only exists temporarily for a user (being created by the "partial search" located above). How can you access in the controller a temporary param to be displayed in the view?